# PHP to connect to remote Parse MongoDB; cURL works on command line but PHP file_get_contents doesn't

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mongodb, parse-platform

I am working with a Wordpress site with CPanel and a MySQL database. I want to be able to read data from a MongoDB held on Parse.com. Eventually, I want to change Wordpress's login.php script to search through the MongoDB and create users if necessary.

I am having lots of trouble connecting to the database.

Here is my php script:

```
<?php    
    $url = 'http://mercury.example.com:2234/parse/login';
    $data = array('username' => 'username', 'password' => 'password');
    $appID = "X-Parse-Application-Id: parseAppID";
    $restKey = "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: praseRESTapiKey";
    $session = "X-Parse-Revocable-Session: 1"; 
    $contentType = "Content-Type: application/json";

    $context = array(
        'http'=> array(
                "method" => "GET",
                "header" => $appID . $restKey . $session . $contentType,
                "content" => http_build_query($data)));

    $context = stream_context_create($context);
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    var_dump($result);

?>
```

The errors I am receiving are:

```
Notice: file_get_contents(): Content-type not specified assuming application/x-www-form-urlencoded in C:\wamp\www\parseDB.php on line 26

Warning: file_get_contents(http://mercury.example.com:2234/parse/login): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in C:\wamp\www\parseDB.php on line 26
```

From my understanding, the 403 error means the web server is returning the "forbidden" status code.

I am testing my php script on localhost using WAMP. A colleague of mine tried to run a similar command on Bash and received a response. (I broke it out so it is easier to read).

```
curl -X GET 
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: parseAppID" 
-H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: parseRESTapiKey" 
-H "X-Parse-Revocable-Session: 1" 
-G --data-urlencode 'username=username' --data-urlencode 'password=password' 
http://mercury.example.com:2234/parse/login
```

I have been stuck on this for 2 days so far, and I have no idea what is going on. I appreciate all the help I can get.

EDIT
Here is my final solution:

```
$url = 'http://mercury.example.com:3432/parse/login';
$data = array('username' => 'USERNAME', 'password' => 'PASSWORD!');

$context = array(
    'http'=> array(
        'method' => "GET",
        'header' => "X-Parse-Application-Id: APPID\r\n" . 
                    "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: RESTAPIKEY\r\n" . 
                    "X-Parse-Revocable-Session: 1" . 
                    "Content-Type: application/json\r\n",
        'content' => http_build_query($data)        
        )
    );
$context = stream_context_create($context);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
var_dump($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the stream_content_create example at http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php which explains how to pass headers properly. At this time, you slam each header together without any line feeds which will make them look like concatenated string:

`X-Parse-Application-Id: parseAppIDX-Parse-REST-API-Key: praseRESTapiKeyX-Parse-Revocable-Session: 1Content-Type: application/json`

*Hint - add `\r\n` after each header line.*

Instead of file_get_contents you could also use `curl` methods.

Comment: That was exactly the issue. Worked like a charm. My infinite gratitude goes to you.